# Left join fails to give correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table1 is set as:

| County | County_Name | Type | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-01 | 1000 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-02 | 1000 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-03 | 1000 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-04 | 1000 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-05 | 1000 |
| A | A1 | NON-BASE | 2024-01-06 | 1000 |

Table2 is set as:

| City | County_Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | BASE |
| B | A1 | NON-BASE |
| C | A1 | NON-BASE |
| D | A1 | BASE |
| E | A1 | NON-BASE |
| F | A1 | BASE |
| G | A1 | NON-BASE |
| H | A1 | BASE |
| I | A1 | NON-BASE |
| J | A1 | NON-BASE |

I need to build a final table by joining Table1 with Table2 by adding two new columns to table1 that should display `count` of `City` column from Table2 as:

| County | County_Name | Type | Date | Value | City_Count_Base | City_Count_NonBase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-01 | 1000 | 6 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-02 | 1000 | 6 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-03 | 1000 | 6 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-04 | 1000 | 6 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-05 | 1000 | 6 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-06 | 1000 | 0 | 4 |

I tried writing the query as below but it does not give me the correct results:

```
SELECT 
    county
    , Table1.county_Name
    , Table1.Type
    , Date
    , Value
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.Type = 'BASE' THEN City END) OVER (PARTITION BY Table1.County_Name, Table1.Type) AS City_Count_Base
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.Type = 'NON-BASE' THEN City END) OVER (PARTITION BY Table1.County_Name, Table1.Type) AS City_Count_NonBase
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.County_Name = Table2.Count_Name 
    AND Table1.Type = Table2.Type
```

Comment: What is wrong with your results? (We can't see them). A fiddle demonstrating the issue would help

Comment: "*display count of City column from Table1*" There is no City column in table 1. Your expected results don't seem to match up with your data. I count 4 base and 6 non-base cities, you seem to have it reversed. And the last county row should be non-base? Your query has typos like `Table2.Count_Name`. Would you double check your question, please, so there's no confusion?

Comment: Your query needs a [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause to tell the query how to group for counting. Seems to be by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using outer apply. The sub query gets the grouped by counts and applies them to the outer query where the county name and type match.

**Outer Apply Example**

```
SELECT 
    County
    ,county_Name
    ,Type
    ,Date
    ,Value
    ,City_Count_Base
    ,City_Count_NonBase
FROM #tmp1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        Count(Case when Type='BASE' then city end)  City_Count_Base,
        Count(Case when Type='NON-BASE' then city end)  City_Count_NonBase
    FROM #tmp2 
    WHERE #tmp1.County_Name = County_Name 
      AND #tmp1.Type = Type
    GROUP BY 
        County_Name, Type
) totals
```

**Test Data**

```
create table #tmp1(County nchar(1), County_Name nvarchar(50), Type nvarchar(50), Date date, Value int)
insert into #tmp1
values
('A', 'A1', 'BASE',     '2024-01-01',   1000),
('A', 'A1', 'BASE',     '2024-01-02',   1000),
('A', 'A1', 'BASE',     '2024-01-03',   1000),
('A', 'A1', 'BASE',     '2024-01-04',   1000),
('A', 'A1', 'BASE',     '2024-01-05',   1000),
('A', 'A1', 'NON-BASE', '2024-01-06',   1000)

create table #tmp2(city nchar(1), County_Name nvarchar(50), Type nvarchar(50))
insert into #tmp2
values
('A',   'A1', 'BASE'    ),
('B',   'A1', 'NON-BASE'),
('C',   'A1', 'NON-BASE'),
('D',   'A1', 'BASE'    ),
('E',   'A1', 'NON-BASE'),
('F',   'A1', 'BASE'    ),
('G',   'A1', 'NON-BASE'),
('H',   'A1', 'BASE'    ),
('I',   'A1', 'NON-BASE'),
('J',   'A1', 'NON-BASE')
```

**Results**

| County | county_Name | Type | Date | Value | City_Count_Base | City_Count_NonBase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-01 | 1000 | 4 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-02 | 1000 | 4 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-03 | 1000 | 4 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-04 | 1000 | 4 | 0 |
| A | A1 | BASE | 2024-01-05 | 1000 | 4 | 0 |
| A | A1 | NON-BASE | 2024-01-06 | 1000 | 0 | 6 |

Comment: thanks. I had edited the question as well.